# File transfer using P2P TCP protocol

Tags: c#, .net, tcp, p2p

Im going to start a project in C# using Windows Forms which will use P2P and we choosed the TCP protocol, because the file transfer dont have any size limit, but I never made a P2P connection, does someone have some knowledge about where should I get any documentation or any framework to start,if this question is already done please make sure to comment where its done.

Comment: You don't need frameworks just to open TCP connections.

Comment: So its already implemented in C#? I wont have any problems with firewalls or port issues?

Comment: I didn't say that. But that doesn't mean the only way to implement P2P protocols is to use a framework that does all the work for you. You can start with the basics and then as need arises add some lightweight library or use whatever is present in C#.

Comment: Ok so, do you know any site where they explain how to open the specified port and pass through the firewall in detail?

Comment: http://portforward.com/ - typically you only need to port forward the router. The Windows Firewall usually doesn't block connections that you open (but if it does it will ask you if you want to allow them or not).